# R: Why am I getting an extra column titled "X.1" in my dataframe after reading my .txt file?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have got this .txt file outputed by a microscope to process.

```
#read the .txt file generated by microscope, skipping the first 9 lines of garbage information
df <- read.csv("Objects_Population - AllCells.txt", sep="\t", skip = 9,header=TRUE, fill = T)
```

Then I started looking at the structure of the dataframe, everything seems fine except I now found an extra column in the end of the data frame named "x.1" and all rows of it are NA values. I don't see this column when I open the .txt file in excel. I suspect the problem has something to do with the column names generated by microscope, they contain quite some special characters

Below is the dataframe read by Excel(only showing the last 2 columns since I have 132 columns, and their names are disgustingly long):

```
AllCells - Cell Contact Area with Neighbors [%] AllCells - Nucleus Nearest Neighbor Distance [Âµm]
0                                               4.82083
21.9512                                         0
15.7895                                         0
29.4118                                         0.584611
0                                               4.21569
0                                               1.99599
0                                               3.50767
...
```

This has happened to me before but I never took it too serious as I was always interested in a subset of my data frame. Now I'm looking at all columns then this starts to bothering me.

Is there any way I can read them correctly without R attaching that additional "X.1" column in the end? Preferably not manually delete or subset out the last column...

Cheers,
ML

Comment: Note that if your file is TAB delimited, you should use `read.delim` not `read.csv`

Comment: Thank you, @Hong Ooi, yes I should be more strict with what I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all other column names are correct, you have probably a trailing `\t` in the text file. R tries to include it and gives it the generic column name `X.1`.

You could try and read the file first as 'plain text' and remove the trailing `\t` and only then use `read.csv`:

```
file_connection <- file("Objects_Population - AllCells.txt")
content <- readLines(file_connection )
close(file_connection)
```

Now we try to get rid of these trailing `\t` (this might need some testing to fit your needs)

```
sanitized <- gsub("\\t$", "", content)
```

And then we read this sanitized string as if it was a file (using the argument `text`)

```
df <- read.csv(text=paste0(sanitized, collapse="\n"), sep="\t", skip = 9,header=TRUE, fill = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had that problem too. Fixed it by saving the file as "CSV (MS-DOS (*csv)" instead of what I originally had as "CSV (Comma delimited)(*csv)".

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because you've got an extra empty column in your spreadsheet.

In Excel, open your sheet and press Ctrl-End. If you end up in an empty cell outside the range of your data, there's the problem. Select the column (Ctrl-Space), right-click, and choose Delete.

Comment: Hi @Hong Ooi, thank you for your quick response. I open the file in excel and did what you suggested. However it lands perfectly on the last well with correct data...

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered similar problem.  I found that three extra columns were created (X, X.1, X.2), after I loaded dataset from excel sheet to R studio.

Steps Followed by me:

a) I went to the excel sheet and selected those three extra columns after last column with actual values in excel sheet. Selected extra 3 columns by keeping cursor on top of columns and then right click the mouse and select delete.

b) Again loaded that excel sheet in R. I did not find those 3 columns.